# update frequency of recaptcha analytics

Tags: recaptcha

We recently got reCAPTCHA on one of our sites.
Im getting asked to pull out the data, which is pretty simple and is all fine in CSV format and everything.

My question(s) is when do the data update? It seems like its every 24hrs, but im not really sure.
Also is there a way to get more data than the "Date,no CAPTCHAs,Passed CAPTCHAs,Failed CAPTCHAs,Total Sessions,Failed Sessions,Average Response Time (seconds),Average score"?

Thanks in advance

Reading the analytics FAQ

Comment: So without being 100% sure, it seems like the data updates at around 10:00 CET everyday. So on a 24hr basis.

Would still like to know the exact update timeframe though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reCAPTCHA Enterprise you can use the `GetMetrics` [gRPC endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1#google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseService.GetMetrics) or [REST endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.keys/getMetrics). This will return metrics about both Scores and Challenges (CAPTCHAs).

```json
{
  "name": string,
  "startTime": string,
  "scoreMetrics": [
    {
      object (ScoreMetrics)
    }
  ],
  "challengeMetrics": [
    {
      object (ChallengeMetrics)
    }
  ]
}
```

These metrics should be approximately real-time, that values should change within ~minutes of events occurring.

Comment: Hello Cory,
Thanks for the answer. At the moment im using v2 - Getting the scores and challenges in realtime could be usefull. But im more curious when/what time the update happens.